# how to get two radio button values in( ALL )radio button , note All is a radio button in my code

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2

```
This the code

<label class="opetionLabel">
                    <input class="col-4 optionStyle" type="radio" name="select_all" value="all">  All.
                    </label>

                    <label class="opetionLabel">    
                    <input class="col-4 optionStyle" type="radio" name="select_all" value="From Station" > From Station 
                    </label>

                    <label class="opetionLabel">    
                    <input class="col-4 optionStyle takeClass" type="radio" name="select_all" value="ToStation ">  ToStation 
                    </label>
```

i want to fire a query that will help to get 2nd and 3rd button values in All radio Button How to do that

Answer (score 1):

You can use eq() method of jQuery library to do it. Bear in mind that the index of the DOM elements, used by eq() method starts from 0.
To get the second input's value, we need to call index number 1.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var second = $('input[name=select_all]').eq(1).val();
    var third = $('input[name=select_all]').eq(2).val();
    alert(second);
    alert(third);
});
```